# Prove $(n!) ^2 > n^n$ for all $n > 3$ using Induction

Tags: inequality, induction, factorial

Prove $(n!) ^2 > n^n$ for all $n > 3$ by induction.
I know that we will have to use Binomial theorem somehow but I can't figure out how?
Please provide some hint.

Comment: You don’t need binomial theorem, Bernoulli inequality suffices.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Proceed as usual by

- base case
- induction step: $$(n!)^2>n^n \implies ((n+1)!)^2>(n+1)^{n+1}$$

then consider

$$((n+1)!)^2=(n+1)^2(n!)^2\stackrel{Ind. Hyp.}>(n+1)^2n^n\stackrel{?}>(n+1)^{n+1}$$

therefore to conclude we need to prove the last inequality that is

$$(n+1)^2n^n\stackrel{?}>(n+1)^{n+1}$$

Comment: Can you please explain the last step i.e. from (n+1)^2 n^n to(n+1)^n+1?

Comment: It is the step we need to prove, indeed note that I’ve put “?” for the inequality.

Comment: @SaswatKumarPati Note that is we prove that inequality we can conclude form the chain $$((n+1)!)^2=(n+1)^2(n!)^2\stackrel{Ind. Hyp.}>(n+1)^2n^n>(n+1)^{n+1}$$ that $$((n+1)!)^2>(n+1)^{n+1}$$ which is the induction step.

Answer (score 2):

Hint for the induction step:

$(n+1)^2n^n>(n+1)^{n+1} \iff (1+1/n)^n<n+1$.

Comment: That's a big big hint :)

Answer (score 0):

On the left side, $$\frac{(n+1)!^2}{n!^2}=(n+1)^2$$ and on the right side

$$\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{n^n}=(n+1)\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n=(n+1)\left(1+\frac nn+\frac{n(n-1)}{n^22!}+\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{n^33!}+\cdots\right).$$

Then

$$\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n=1+\frac nn+\frac{n(n-1)}{n^22!}+\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{n^33!}+\cdots<1+1+\frac12+\frac1{3!}+\cdots<e.$$