# Proof for $(n!)^2 \geq n^n$ without using induction

Tags: inequality

The question is to prove that
$$
(n!)^2 \geq n^n \text{ | } n\in\mathbb{N}
$$

My attempt:

From the general AM-GM inequality, we have
$$
\frac{a_1+a_2+a_3+\cdots+a_n}{n} \geq \sqrt[n]{a_1a_2a_3\cdots a_n}
$$

Taking
$$
a_r=\frac{1}{r^2}
$$
we get

$$
\begin{aligned}
&\left(\frac{1+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n^2}}{n}\right)^n > \left(\frac{1}{1.2^2.3^2\cdots n^2}\right) \\
\implies & \left(\frac{1+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n^2}}{n}\right)^n > \frac{1}{(n!)^2} \\
\implies & (n!)^2 > \left(\frac{n}{1+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n^2}}\right)^n
\end{aligned}
$$
If
$$
\left(1+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^n=k
$$
Then, we have
$$
(n!)^2 > \frac{n^n}{k}
$$
and I'm stuck. Help please!

Comment: What about $n=1$?

Comment: @Joe And also $n=2$.

Comment: After you fix the typo, $\frac{((n+1)!)^2/(n+1)^{n+1}}{(n!)^2/n^2}=(n+1)(1+1/n)^{-n}\geq (n+1)e^{-1}$. So, for $n>2$ one term of $\frac{(n!)^2}{n^n}$ to the next differ by a factor grater than $1$. So, you only need to check the first few values $n=1,2$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show that if $n>2$, then $(n!)^2>n^n$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/640602/show-that-if-n2-then-n2nn)

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2919901/42969.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that $n! \gt \sqrt{n^n}, n \geq 3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106126/prove-that-n-sqrtnn-n-geq-3)

Comment: I've edited the question to the right proposition. Also I'd like to prove this without using induction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$$(n!)^2=(1\cdot n)\cdot(2\cdot (n-1))\cdots((n-1)\cdot 2)\cdot(n\cdot 1)$$

Then show:

$$k\cdot (n+1-k)\geq n$$

for $k=1,\dots,n,$ with equality only when $k=1$ or $k=n.$

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about $n\geq3$, otherwise your proposition is false. Your proof could be done by induction. The base case, $n=3$, is trivially shown. For the inductive step, let us consider the functions:
$$f(k)=\left(1+\frac 1k\right)^k$$ and $$g(k)=k+1$$
Try to show that for all $k\geq 3$, $g(k)>f(k)$. For this, you can use calculus. Notice that both $f$ and $g$ are monotonically increasing and both $g(3)>f(3)$ and $\lim_{k\to \infty}g(k)>\lim_{k\to \infty}f(k)$. Once you've proven this, if we take a statement $S_k$ as: "$(k!)^2>k^k$". Then,
$$k+1>\left(1+\frac 1k\right)^k$$ So,
$$(k+1)k^k>(k+1)^k$$
So, $$k^k>(k+1)^{k-1}...(1)$$
Which means, $$(k+1)^2 k^k>(k+1)^{k+1}$$
Now, multiplying $(k+1)^2$ on both sides of $S_k$, we get:
$$((k+1)!)^2>(k+1)^2 k^k...(2)$$
Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$, you get that $S_{k+1}$ is also true.
QED.